# I am facing this issue when I am running react-native run-android

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-emulator, expo

I am using the java version 1.8 and its working good in iOS but in react native it throws an exception and i can't figure it out.
Please help[image]

Comment: open that project on android studio and sync and try run

Comment: any other way please? I did it

Comment: it seems dependency issue only is synced successfully?

Comment: I am new to react native so I dont know much.. I had a question that should i run only the android part in android studio or run the whole project named "cometgraphic".

Comment: open android project on android studio and install required dependency automatically it do.  after sync successful run on cmd 'react-native run-android'

Comment: I am doing it brother.. I really hope it works.. frustrated on this since morning

Comment: Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar
It came something like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182351/discussion-between-prasanth-s-and-rishav-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Open project on android studio and install required dependency. after sync successful run on terminal `'react-native run-android'`